# UI tools to connect to strimzi kafka cluster

Tags: apache-kafka, strimzi

Looking for UI tools to connect to Strimzi kafka cluster to get visibility to kafka topics, read messages within topics, broker and partition details and ability to connect with or without SSL/SASL connections.I have already tried using kafka tool and facing issues with it hence looking for an alternative). Kindly suggest some UI tools for the same ? ( similar to confluent center/kafka tool) which are either free or with minimal cost.

Comment: Sorry, tool and other suggestions are off-topic for StackOverflow

Comment: from kafka tool I am unable to connect and I haven't found anything on the internet either, if anyone can please suggest ?

Comment: @Maazen There are plenty options, e.g.: https://github.com/cloudhut/kowl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no UI tools for now but a new issue was started about it. I would follow it https://github.com/strimzi/strimzi-kafka-operator/issues/3287

Comment: Sir actually we are able to connect to our strimzi kafka cluster using plaintext connection but when we use SASL that's when we cannot . Is there a way around ( or currently no UI tool or any hack is not available to connect to strimzi cluster) , any advice is much appreciated ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a project in early stage of developement: https://github.com/strimzi/strimzi-ui

> Strimzi UI provides a way for managing Strimzi and Kafka clusters (+
> other components) deployed by it using a graphical user interface.

But unforunately in the moment of writing:

> This UI is currently not in a state where it can be used. Is it still
> early on in it's development but we hope to have something usable very
> soon!

So, keep an eye on it.